# Twig macros+blocks or something?

Tags: twig

Im new to Twig. Is there something similar to Jade's mixins with nested blocks?
I mean something like this:

```
mixin button(text)
  .btn
    .txt= text
    .dropdown
      block

+button("button")
  +button("sub1")
    +button("sub1-1")
    +button("sub1-2")
  +button("sub2")
    +button("sub2-1")
    .custom1 blah-blah
  +button("sub3")
    +button("sub3-1")
    +button("sub3-2")
```

Comment: Can you explain what would be the html result of the given code?

Comment: @AlainTiemblo it looks like i found solution. Idk how good it is but it works for me. It would be better to have same result by using a single macro, but i still cant find how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I found some kind of solution.
I have just splitted macro into 2+ macros.

```
{% __btns.twig %}
{% macro btn1_opening(text) %}
    <div class="button1">
        <div class="text">{{ text }}</div>
        <div class="dropdown">
{% endmacro %}

{% macro btn1_closing() %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}

{# main.twig #}
{% import "__btns.twig" as btns %}
{{ btns.btn1_opening("I am button") }}
    <div class="something-inside-dropdown">
        {% include "somefile.twig" %}
    </div>
{{ btns.btn1_closing() }}
```

So, in this case even if i need multiple blocks inside of my macro i can just write some HTML between opening, intermediate and closing macros.